# количество строк на label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Приветствую! Помогите, разобраться с label. Хочу сделать много строчный label, как дисплей, что б информация размещалась там сверху вниз. Т.е. нажимаю на одну кнопку информация на 1-ой строке появляется, а нажал другую на 2-ой строке. Нашел один код, но что то у меня не получается с ним.

```
    - (void)configureTableWithData:(NSArray*)dataObjects {
[self.table setNumberOfRows:[dataObjects count] withRowType:@"mainRowType"];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.table.numberOfRows; i++) {
    MainRowType* theRow = [self.table rowControllerAtIndex:i];
    MyDataObject* dataObj = [dataObjects objectAtIndex:i];

    [theRow.rowDescription setText:dataObj.text];
    [theRow.rowIcon setImage:dataObj.image];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

например вот так это можно сделать

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.label.text = @"line";
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 100)];
    [button setTitle:@"add line" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)tap:(id)sender
{
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", self.label.text, @"another line"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Не выходит. Нажимая вторую кнопку, информация просто меняется на новую, а с первой кнопки пропадает. Может это лучше не в Label делать?!

Comment: Разобрался, вроде, что то уже есть. Только как сделать, что б название выходило только один раз, а то он каждый раз повторяет название? У меня счетчик количества нажатий. Просто надо, что б снизу появлялась вторая кнопка с количеством нажатий.

Answer (score 1):

Это ты уже в таблицу полез. Тебе нужно по первой кнопке ставить label.numberOfLines = 1. По второй кнопке - label.numberOfLines = 2.

Текст для label должен содержать "\n" в качестве разделителя строк (так удобней просто).

Comment: Не выходит. Нажимая вторую кнопку, информация просто меняется на новую, а с первой кнопки пропадает. Может это лучше не в Label делать?!

Comment: первая кнопка просто ставит label.numberOfLines = 1, с нее информация никак не может пропасть. Видимо, ты сам случайно кнопку задел.
Label тут подходит замечательно, если я правильно понял задачу.